# mvc,How to prevent clicking the browser's back button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser

i have an activity that has 2 steps,each step has own view,Step 2 begins when the first step is over,and user is in second view ,in step 2, The user should not be able to click the browser's back button.
maybe it will be good if i can show a message for user,but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the back button, you can use the following code on the second page.

```
window.onload = function () {
if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
    };
}
else {
    var ignoreHashChange = true;
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        if (!ignoreHashChange) {
            ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.location.hash = Math.random();
            // Detect and redirect change here
            // Works in older FF and IE9
            // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
            // delimiter on the end of the URL
        }
        else {
            ignoreHashChange = false;   
        }
    };
}
```

}